# parsing diagonal double array

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing

Im making a parser for file like this:

```
intrepideg
xtdcvmhgze
yrwhoejkpn
minusculet
isnqdhivpi
ntznyafhel
ceamgnqgug
erpoxtavrf
gwaupsgwsd
kyqtendrme
```

The idea is to receive a string from user and then searching it all horizontal, vertical and then diagonal.
I struggle with the diagonal way because i search the optimal way for making the less iteration possible.
Should i make 4 passage begining at each corner of the double array, find the middle of the double array and then make 2 passage from to beginining ? what is the best algorythm ?

here is the core function of my program:

```
t_inco          search_all(t_inco inco)
{
  int           i;
  int           f;
  int           j;

  i = 0;
  f = 0;
  j = 0;
  while (inco.map[i])
    {
      while(inco.map[i][f])
        {
          if (inco.map[i][f] == inco.wd[0])
            {
              if(find_cases_h(inco, i, f))
                {
                  inco = get_cases(inco, i, f, 1);
                  return(inco);
                }
              else if(find_cases_v(inco, i, f))
                {
                  inco = get_cases(inco, i, f, 2);
                  return(inco);
                }
              else if(find_cases_d(inco, i, f))
                {
                  inco = get_cases(inco, i, f, 3);
                  return(inco);
                }
            }
          f++;
        }
      i++;
      f = 0;
    }
  return(inco);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you make 4 passes, each one starting at a different corner. For example, given your array:

```
intrepideg
xtdcvmhgze
yrwhoejkpn
minusculet
isnqdhivpi
ntznyafhel
ceamgnqgug
erpoxtavrf
gwaupsgwsd
kyqtendrme
```

Starting at the upper-left corner, you would search on the diagonal moving down from right to left. So: "i", "nx", "tty", "rdrm", etc. On the upper-right corner, search "g", "ee", "dzn", etc: the diagonal that moves down from left to right.

Although that's more passes through the array, it makes for much simpler code than trying to search all four diagonals in a single scan of the array.

You could potentially do it in two passes. After all, the search of the diagonal moving down from right to left is just a reversal of the diagonal moving up from left to right. So you could set up your iteration for the first pass to search "i", "nx", "xn", "tty", "ytt", "rdrm", "mrdr", etc. The difference in speed wouldn't be much, though, and it would complicate your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to think of this like a game of breakout. Let a 'ball' 'bounce' around diagonally inside the array. Make the array such a size that the ball would bounce and hit every letter. I'd guess this might not be a very optimal method, and am not sure if it's even possible for the ball to hit every letter (re the corners), but this might be an interesting approach to test out for the curious :-)